# Animate.css messes up image position

Tags: css, image, position, jquery-animate, animate.css

For a project of mine, I am trying to use animate.css on an image to make it slide in from the right. While the position is fine, when not having the animate.css classes 'animated slideInRight', it messes up when the classes are applied. Here is a picture of what I mean. The picture positions below the text, when it should take its original position beside the text.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<section class="section section-responsive">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="responsive-text">
      <h3 class="responsive-h3">Mobile Websites</h3>
      <h2 class="responsive-h2">Für eine mobile Welt</h2>
      <p class="responsive-p">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="responsive-img js--wp-3">
     <img src="Resources/img/mockupcut.png" alt="Responsive Webdesign" class="responsive-mockup">
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
.section-responsive {
    position: relative;
    height: 80vh;
}

.responsive-text {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.responsive-h3 {
    color: #f52945;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 220%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.responsive-h2 {
    color: #f52945;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 220%;
    margin: -15px 0 30px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.responsive-p {
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 145%;
    width: 70%;
}

.responsive-mockup {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.js--wp-3').waypoint(function(direction) {
            $('.js--wp-3').addClass('animated slideInRight'); 
        }, {
            offset: '100%'
        });
```

Comment: Is the `offset: 100` setting the position it lands or the position it starts?

Comment: it's the position it starts

Comment: Hint: There is no picture uploaded to pic-upload.de / Lads am besten nochmal hoch und füg den Bild link so ein wie ich es vorbereitet habe ;)

Comment: I don't see anything in your CSS for `.js--wp-3`. It should have some styling to determine it's position.

Comment: I specified the position for .js--wp-3, but it still messes it up

Comment: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/171221/ns2bfcxu.png

Comment: @nickmeister Try recreating the issue in JSFiddle or CodePen to see if the issue is still happening. That'll make it easier to debug.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nickmeister/pen/aEZMXm Here I hope that's alright if you need anything else, just let me know.

Comment: @SamJohnson Do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @nickmeister Sorry, was away for Christmas - have you sorted the issue?